# Vlookup Equivalent False condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data required as below

I would like to go back 1 yr for each date available in date field and bring the closing rate of trading day falling on (mk_dt -365 days), if the date is trading holiday then previous day closing rate should be fetched i.e 20221107, if in 20221107 is not available then it should fetch data from 20221106

| mk_dt | mk_exchange | mk_scripcd | mk_closerate | 1yrbackdate | 1yrbackrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20231108 | N | 500325 | 2335.9 | 20221107 | 2606.6 |
| 20231107 | N | 500325 | 2335.9 | 20221107 | 2606.6 |

I have tried recursive CTE and what not but failed miserably
It is similar to False condition in Excel Vlookup
Your help will be appreciated

```
CREATE TABLE [Market_Rates]
(
    [mk_scripcd] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [mk_exchange] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [mk_dt] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [mk_openrate] [money] NULL,
    [mk_highrate] [money] NULL,
    [mk_lowrate] [money] NULL,
    [mk_closerate] [money] NULL,
    [mkrid] [char](8) NULL,
    [mkrdt] [char](8) NULL
)  

INSERT INTO Market_Rates 
VALUES ('500325', 'N', '20221107', 2591, 2610.3, 2574, 2606.6, 'ADMIN', '20231122');
INSERT INTO Market_Rates 
VALUES ('500325', 'N', '20221109', 2610.3, 2621.95, 2590.05, 2604, 'ADMIN', '20231122');
INSERT INTO Market_Rates 
VALUES ('500325', 'N', '20221110', 2590, 2596.55, 2563, 2572.5, 'ADMIN', '20231122');
INSERT INTO Market_Rates 
VALUES ('500325', 'N', '20221111', 2600, 2636, 2588, 2631.8, 'ADMIN', '20231122');
INSERT INTO Market_Rates 
VALUES ('500325', 'N', '20221114', 2630.75, 2642, 2605.15, 2619.05, 'ADMIN', '20231122');
INSERT INTO Market_Rates 
VALUES ('500325', 'N', '20221115', 2622.3, 2626.4, 2590, 2607.3, 'ADMIN', '20231122');
INSERT INTO Market_Rates 
VALUES ('500325', 'N', '20221116', 2610, 2615.95, 2581.35, 2592.35, 'ADMIN', '20231122');
INSERT INTO Market_Rates 
VALUES ('500325', 'N', '20221117', 2584.95, 2613, 2580, 2599.05, 'ADMIN', '20231122');
INSERT INTO Market_Rates 
VALUES ('500325', 'N', '20221118', 2606.75, 2609, 2571.1, 2597.65,  'ADMIN', '20231122');
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221121',2588,2588,2543.1,2550.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221122',2545,2568.5,2536.5,2565.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221123',2575,2577.9,2552.25,2557.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221124',2566,2594,2548.2,2579.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221125',2589,2624.9,2582.1,2617.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221128',2608.9,2721.05,2502,2707.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221129',2703.95,2731.65,2694,2712.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221130',2712.5,2745.45,2698.2,2731.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221201',2741.8,2755,2716,2723.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221202',2730,2748,2700.6,2722.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221205',2712,2716.75,2678,2682.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221206',2665.1,2697,2661,2690.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221207',2685,2695,2642.15,2650.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221208',2660,2665,2640.1,2649.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221209',2646,2660,2601.85,2609.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221212',2585.5,2623,2585,2613.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221213',2613.1,2633,2606.7,2625,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221214',2637.65,2638.95,2611,2615.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221215',2602.5,2615,2571,2578.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221216',2571,2618.8,2558.15,2565.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221219',2581,2604,2566.7,2599.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221220',2583.9,2626,2566,2621.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221221',2621,2633,2576.1,2584.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221222',2598,2604.65,2566.75,2577.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221223',2563.3,2590.5,2492.25,2502.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221226',2514.75,2542,2492.4,2524.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221227',2530,2548.8,2515.25,2544.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221228',2538,2549.8,2521.5,2544.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221229',2527,2548.9,2525.5,2543.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20221230',2545.1,2577,2541.1,2547.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230102',2550,2579,2548.2,2575.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230103',2565.05,2573,2547.8,2557.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230104',2557,2561.05,2514,2518.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230105',2523.5,2536.4,2504,2514.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230106',2526.65,2547.95,2518.3,2536.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230109',2545.3,2602,2543.35,2596.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230110',2606,2606,2546,2558.4,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230111',2552.5,2558,2521.1,2526.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230112',2524.85,2532.5,2465,2471.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230113',2458.4,2472.9,2434.6,2467.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230116',2472.7,2479.65,2427,2444.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230117',2458,2483,2450.6,2478.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230118',2473.5,2491.1,2460.35,2474.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230119',2472.9,2481.15,2456.65,2472.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230120',2475,2475,2437.25,2442.65,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230123',2449,2466.2,2425,2430.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230124',2440,2443.65,2387.35,2415.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230125',2412.45,2414.7,2380,2382.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230127',2384.4,2387.35,2311.65,2337.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230130',2331.7,2371.9,2301,2359.75,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230131',2382,2387.65,2341,2353.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230201',2379.95,2379.95,2305,2339.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230202',2318,2348,2311,2326.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230203',2349,2349,2293,2329,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230206',2315,2321,2305.8,2311.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230207',2312,2327.4,2293,2305.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230208',2313,2359.9,2307,2351.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230209',2353.45,2370.85,2334,2356.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230210',2354.9,2354.9,2321.3,2336.65,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230213',2340.2,2350,2313.55,2323.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230214',2329.95,2381.9,2323.65,2378.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230215',2376,2437.2,2373,2431.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230216',2449.45,2463.8,2425.05,2430.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230217',2420,2447.5,2410.6,2440.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230220',2445,2449.75,2410.1,2414.4,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230221',2424,2446.8,2412.35,2434.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230222',2425.95,2430,2375.05,2378.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230223',2378,2394.75,2361.35,2367.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230224',2372,2396.15,2368,2383.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230227',2382,2389.65,2351.7,2367.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230228',2356.1,2367,2313.65,2322.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230301',2344,2345.5,2323.25,2343.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230302',2337,2351.65,2321.6,2326.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230303',2349.15,2393.45,2341.55,2385.4,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230306',2400,2424.6,2400,2408.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230308',2408.7,2419,2385,2417.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230309',2416,2416.9,2355.1,2359.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230310',2341.5,2344,2315.05,2322.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230313',2329,2344,2275,2284.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230314',2280,2304.95,2269.05,2275.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230315',2284.1,2298.3,2227.4,2237.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230316',2243,2254,2202.2,2225.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230317',2244.75,2251.95,2212.7,2223.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230320',2215,2220,2180,2201.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230321',2218.95,2274,2217,2269.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230322',2285,2291.45,2270,2276.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230323',2268,2269.9,2243.05,2247.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230324',2245.25,2250,2198,2203.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230327',2217.5,2254,2200.2,2237.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230328',2245,2256.5,2237,2248,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230329',2239,2244.8,2211.1,2234.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230331',2255,2343.45,2254.7,2331.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230403',2345,2349,2315,2331.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230405',2348,2348,2308.55,2325.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230406',2318.15,2354,2318.15,2341.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230410',2350,2350.4,2321.55,2324.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230411',2334,2341,2324.05,2336.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230412',2336.35,2367.8,2330.05,2346.65,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230413',2353,2365.8,2342,2355.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230417',2424.95,2424.95,2349.05,2367.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230418',2377,2377,2326,2340.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230419',2339.05,2357.9,2332.2,2352,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230420',2354.1,2359,2332.1,2346.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230421',2350.65,2361,2336.4,2349,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230424',2375,2380.9,2348,2358,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230425',2366,2380.6,2350.5,2376.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230426',2379,2386.1,2354.05,2362.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230427',2375,2384,2364,2377.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230428',2382,2423.9,2381.75,2420.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230502',2436.2,2445.8,2428.1,2441.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230503',2445,2445,2413.05,2420.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230504',2421.15,2452.85,2414.6,2448,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230505',2441,2461.35,2436,2441.75,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230508',2450,2483.65,2444.15,2471.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230509',2475,2486.8,2463.25,2479.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230510',2490,2499.85,2481.2,2496.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230511',2498.95,2509.5,2476.55,2480.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230512',2469.8,2487.4,2456.5,2484.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230515',2489.9,2504.55,2473.15,2489.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230516',2494,2499.6,2450.15,2453.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230517',2463,2465,2429,2439.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230518',2449.55,2457,2427.15,2434.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230519',2434.05,2445.95,2418.85,2441.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230522',2435,2466,2432.35,2455,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230523',2460.65,2468,2451.45,2454.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230524',2445.9,2464,2433.45,2440.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230525',2433.9,2449,2416.05,2439.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230526',2458,2509,2450.75,2506.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230529',2521,2530,2507.2,2520.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230530',2520.6,2537.7,2514.35,2519.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230531',2500,2509.85,2461,2469.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230601',2480.15,2484.9,2458,2463.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230602',2471,2482.85,2451,2455.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230605',2467.2,2483.75,2458.45,2477.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230606',2483.45,2487.7,2462,2479.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230607',2487,2500,2472.6,2498.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230608',2506,2516.85,2491,2499.65,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230609',2507,2508.55,2478,2481.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230612',2475.5,2489.2,2465,2484.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230613',2495,2523.45,2486.25,2520.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230614',2521,2555,2517,2551.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230615',2551.8,2562.55,2535.5,2552.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230616',2560.2,2582.4,2560.2,2577.4,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230619',2584,2584,2542.65,2551.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230620',2547.55,2564,2535,2557.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230621',2557,2569.85,2548,2564.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230622',2556,2573.3,2532,2535.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230623',2528.9,2533.4,2512,2514.75,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230626',2507,2515.4,2488.7,2495.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230627',2496.55,2509.5,2486.65,2496.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230628',2513,2537.85,2497.85,2529.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230630',2546.4,2556.65,2533.45,2550.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230703',2558.05,2622,2555.35,2615.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230704',2625,2625,2573.25,2588.75,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230705',2609,2609,2575.8,2584.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230706',2576.05,2644.45,2576.05,2638.75,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230707',2635,2664.95,2628,2633.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230710',2688.9,2756,2675,2735.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230711',2752.9,2770,2737.6,2764.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230712',2766.3,2802,2761.65,2767.75,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230713',2783.9,2799,2737.25,2743,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230714',2750,2760.9,2725.1,2740.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230717',2747,2815.05,2728,2796.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230718',2817,2837.45,2793,2820.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230719',2830,2856,2797,2841.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230720',2580,2630.95,2580,2619.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230721',2609,2614.9,2523.6,2538.75,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230724',2481,2514.95,2469.3,2487.4,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230725',2494,2505.2,2480,2485.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230726',2485,2547,2485,2526.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230727',2534.05,2537.65,2490.35,2502.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230728',2512.05,2542.85,2500.55,2527.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230731',2527.85,2553.9,2517.95,2549.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230801',2555,2559,2505.3,2513.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230802',2509.2,2512,2463.6,2486.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230803',2475.3,2500.9,2458.05,2475.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230804',2498.8,2516,2471.6,2509.55,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230807',2521,2528.4,2505,2523.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230808',2528,2534.45,2499.55,2508.65,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230809',2504.85,2529,2481.1,2525.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230810',2524.95,2550,2508.45,2536.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230811',2532.45,2558.85,2512.35,2547.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230814',2539,2582.3,2525,2577.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230816',2551,2582.8,2551,2575.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230817',2567.1,2578.1,2532.85,2538,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230818',2531.25,2577.6,2508.55,2556.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230821',2539.95,2555.45,2515.65,2520,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230822',2516.9,2537.95,2499,2519.4,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230823',2524.2,2542.85,2516.95,2522.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230824',2539.9,2539.9,2471,2479.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230825',2456,2505,2442.6,2468.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230828',2472,2484,2431.1,2443.75,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230829',2452.05,2453.45,2408.15,2420.35,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230830',2432,2443,2415,2418.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230831',2423,2425,2399.9,2407,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230901',2406.55,2425.65,2401.65,2412.65,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230904',2412.65,2423.65,2405.3,2410.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230905',2420,2433.95,2412.45,2423.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230906',2421.1,2436.15,2417.25,2428.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230907',2421.7,2438.25,2411,2432,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230908',2440,2456,2422.95,2448.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230911',2452,2476.85,2452,2474.6,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230912',2483,2483,2435.95,2438.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230913',2440,2462.65,2426.25,2451.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230914',2460,2465.8,2445,2453.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230915',2468,2468,2449.5,2457.85,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230918',2440.05,2451,2432.05,2436.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230920',2423.05,2427.6,2355,2382.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230921',2374.95,2390.1,2360,2364.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230922',2376,2382.45,2350,2354.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230925',2350.4,2360.7,2335.1,2340.45,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230926',2338.55,2350.2,2335.6,2342.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230927',2343.5,2371.8,2338.5,2368.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230928',2383,2383,2325,2334.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20230929',2341.8,2369.1,2334.1,2345,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231003',2329.95,2335.6,2316,2318.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231004',2309,2319,2295.1,2314.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231005',2319.25,2329.4,2309,2314.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231006',2317.05,2324.8,2312.05,2318,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231009',2308.1,2311.95,2295,2298.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231010',2306.55,2317.9,2303.75,2308.4,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231011',2314.45,2349.7,2313,2345.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231012',2343.85,2359.35,2338.15,2349.4,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231013',2340,2357.5,2329.15,2349.3,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231016',2345,2354.55,2336,2344.05,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231017',2356,2359.7,2341.3,2355.25,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231018',2355.25,2367,2321,2324,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231019',2312,2321.8,2301,2306.15,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231020',2300,2314.7,2296.3,2299.1,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231023',2290,2306.25,2255.25,2263.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231025',2250.05,2281.2,2243,2257.95,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231026',2251,2258,2220.3,2226.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231027',2240,2273.5,2235.95,2265.8,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231030',2274,2325,2269.95,2312.5,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231031',2328,2328,2282.9,2287.9,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231101',2289.15,2317.5,2275.2,2297.4,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231102',2313.95,2324.3,2307.95,2320.2,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231103',2327.2,2334.95,2315.75,2319.7,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
    Insert Into Market_Rates Values ('500325','N','20231106',2332.3,2340,2325.6,2339,'ADMIN','20231122' ) ;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Are the dates actually stored as `char(n)`

Comment: Will holiday's still be in the data, you just want them handled differently? For example, what would we see in your on 12/25/2022 and 12/25/2023? (Christmas in the US) If you are somewhere that isn't observed assume another example which falls on the same day each year.

Comment: @DaleK I wrote 
WITH Yr1back
AS (
 SELECT mk_dt
  ,mk_scripcd
  ,mk_exchange
  ,mk_closerate
  ,convert(VARCHAR, dateadd(day, - 365, mk_dt), 112) AS "Yr1backdate"
 FROM Market_Rates
 WHERE mk_scripcd = '500325'
  AND mk_exchange = 'N'
 )
SELECT mr.mk_scripcd
 ,mr.mk_dt
 ,mr.mk_exchange
 ,mr.mk_closerate
 ,yr1back.Yr1backdate
 ,Yr1back.mk_closerate
FROM Market_Rates mr
Left JOIN Yr1back ON mr.mk_dt = yr1back.Yr1backdate
 AND mr.mk_scripcd = Yr1back.mk_scripcd
WHERE mr.mk_exchange = 'N'
 AND mr.mk_scripcd = '500325'
 Order by mk_dt desc

Comment: @SalmanA No, It is a Char Field but the dates are stored in YYYYMMDD Format

Comment: @Error_2646, Holidays will not be available in  data, for 12/25/2022 & 12/25/2023 there wont be any record available

Comment: Edit your attempt into your question

Comment: @DaleK, There are no more spaces left in the question hence posted the query in comment

Comment: Well you have way too much sample data, it's supposed to just be a sample not your entire dataset.

Answer (score 2):

A simple outer apply should do it:

```
SELECT
  curr.mk_dt,
  curr.mk_exchange,
  curr.mk_scripcd,
  curr.mk_closerate,
  prev.mk_dt AS [1yrbackdate],
  prev.mk_closerate AS [1yrbackrate]
FROM Market_Rates AS curr
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM Market_Rates
  WHERE mk_dt <= DATEADD(year, -1, curr.mk_dt)
  ORDER BY mk_dt DESC
) AS prev
ORDER BY
  curr.mk_dt
```

Comment: It probably needs a where against the scripcd and exchange field, but it's a bit unclear from the question